# How to `map` an asyncIterator?

Tags: mongodb, bluebird

A recent [mongodb client 3.2.1](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v3.2.1) update says that the cursor is now a proper `Symbol.asyncIterator` to enable `for..await..of` loops.

I had assumed that means it's now a valid iterable for use with `bluebird.map` including the concurrency.

When I try, I get this error: `TypeError: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]`

It indeed works with `for..await..of`

There's a `cursor.forEach` option, but there's no way to set the concurrency, which is why I was using Bluebird's map.
If bluebird doesn't support asyncIterator, are there any drop-in alternatives? e.g. I saw fasy or aigle might be options for some parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [it-batch](https://github.com/achingbrain/it/tree/master/packages/it-batch) to control the concurrency of an async iterable:

```js
const batch = require('it-batch')

const batchedIteratable = batch(cursor, 2) // concurrency: 2
const result = await all(batchedIteratable)
```